# How do I remove my name from the top right corner of Chrome?

Tags: google-chrome

Apparently Chrome updated again and decided to put my name in the top right corner. I don't want to uninstall my "profile" (synched with my Google account)—is there a way to remove the name from the top corner (or to replace it with an image) without damaging my sync settings?

Update: Now [appears as a profile icon](https://superuser.com/q/1355840/57016) in Chrome 69

Comment: This is the most annoying new feature ever introduced in Chrome. I acknowledge that it is useful for people with multiple accounts, but for the large majority of users it is just an annoying and useless widget in the title bar. I hope that Google will never remove the flag to disable this feature.

Comment: Google force-enables that avatar button after Chrome 44.  Here is the change request to "bringing back user control to disable avatar button": https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=513899  Chrome devs are closing all the requests to bring back this user control as: "Wont Fix".  Google is taking a page from the book of Microsoft.  It looks like Google and Chrome is eating from the apple of the tree of good vs evil, figuring out that they too have become Gods, and the users can cry all they want, the Avatar button stays, if you don't like that, then don't use Chrome.  end=near

Comment: I actually preferred to have my name as it is hard to tell the difference between my work and home account by icon.  Is there a flag to bring back the name from the top right corner now that it is gone?  I am on 69.  (He he, can't please everybody)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I used to workaround SO's comment limitation with the `\u200b` trick. Seems that it works just fine with Chrome's avatar menu.

- Open up devtools (⋮ [More Options] > More Tools > Developer Tools)
- On the Console tab, run `copy('\u200b')` to copy a blank space to your clipboard
- Click on the avatar menu, edit the name, paste from the clipboard

Done.

[image: Gone... long gone...]

Comment: This is currently the best solution since the option to remove the menu altogether was removed. Thanks!

Answer (score 18):

**The following instructions no longer disables the avatar menu in Chrome 44** (released July 2015).  Setting the flag to Disabled no longer disables the avatar menu.

To disable, go to the corresponding Chrome setting with the URL below and change the option to `Disabled`

```
chrome://flags/#enable-new-avatar-menu
```

Comment: I don't know why you got downvoted. It works for me.

Comment: I've tried this and it worked.

Comment: No longer working in Chrome 44 (released July 2015)... setting the flag to `Disabled` no longer disables the avatar menu :(

Comment: For chrome 44, add --disable-new-avatar-menu when startich chrome. http://techdows.com/2015/06/chrome-44-disable-user-menu.html

Comment: Flag not there in v63

Answer (score 9):

Here is an easy workaround that works with any version of Chrome (I'm using 49.0.2623.87 at the time of writing). It does not totally remove the name, but it makes it totally invisible with a minimal footprint on the title bar.

- Click on the avatar name in the title bar. A popup appears containing your avatar picture and your name.
- Click on the picture, and the "ManageProfile" window should appear in Chrome
- In the "Name" entry box, simply type a dot '.' and hit ENTER to validate
- Now, your name is replaced by a single dot in the title bar, but all your account parameters (bookmarks, extensions, and so on) are still working

Even better: Chrome does not allow you to use a whitespace as your name, but any Unicode character may be used instead. I suggest to use "Soft Hyphen" (U+00AD) which is totally invisible. I don't know any easy way to enter this character from a keyboard, but simply go to "unicode-table.com" and copy-paste the U+00AD character...

Comment: Stupid, but works :) 

Comment: I am having hard times getting the soft hypen to clipboard :/

Comment: The (now tiny) tab doesn't go away, but it's better than nothing. My original problem was that TeamViewer adds a `<-->` tab to all windows, for easy sharing of that window with others. Unfortunately this was placed right on top of the name tab in Chrome. Not cool. While they still overlap a bit now, it's much easier to hit the TeamViewer tab, without hitting the name tab instead. Excellent :-D

Comment: Direct link may help http://unicode-table.com/en/#00AD ;-)

Answer (score 1):

The following instructions do not remove the avatar button in Chrome 44 and after:

**For Chrome 43 and prior:**

1. Exit from Chrome browser.
2. Right click on its desktop shortcut and select ‘Properties’
3. In the target field, after Chrome.exe add the below switch after giving space and click ‘Apply’

> ```
> --disable-new-avatar-menu
> ```

Tip: You better pin that shortcut to taskbar to launch it quickly. Hold ‘Ctrl’ button, right click on the shortcut and select ‘Pin to taskbar’.

4. If you launch Chrome from taskbar, ensure this: right click on Chrome icon on taskbar, hover over Chrome, right click on it >Properties and check there is the switch we’ve added in target field.

UPDATE: Whole Target field in the Properties dialog should be as below (could be different if you’re using 64-bit Windows)

```
"C:\Program Files\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe"--disable-new-avatar-menu
```

We’ve tested and it worked, let us know if you’ve any doubts in the comments.

Answer (score 0):

Try this :)

You just need to click on the name on right corner of the browser.

1. It gives you pop-up window
   [image]
2. Now click on  remove this person. Google will save your synchronization, again when you try to install new chrome you have to sign in on chrome with the same account and you will get the same synchronized data.(Bookmarks, Favorite, etc.)

Comment: This doesn't solves the problem: the new avatar menu will still be enabled. The only true solution is to disable the flag, as in [this answer](http://superuser.com/a/864053/40690)

Comment: You can change your display name if you click on it under the picture.

Answer (score 0):

Setting > People > Then select your account > Edit > Then erase your name or simply put any character instead of your name.

Answer (score 0):

Update to Version 48.

In Chrome Version 48, it *is* removed. Instead, there is icon that you can click, which opens a drop down, and the name is in there.

At least, the name is not visible until clicked, and it is not visible in screen copies.

Comment: Nope, you're just not logged in.

Answer (score 0):

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bfnQ0.jpg)

You can just enter this code (in the screenshot) in place of your name from the Character Map: Combining Grapheme Joiner U+034F

This is for Windows 10 1709

Posted 10.21.2017

Comment: Read over ["Why do I need 50 reputation to comment"](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead) to ensure you understand how you can start commenting. Also, consider looking over the ["Style guide for questions and answers"](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/18614/style-guide-for-questions-and-answers) to ensure you understand how to write the best Q&A you can.

Answer (score -1):

Go to chrome://settings/
Disconnect the user in the "Sign in" section.

Also you can click the image in the top right by clicking on your profile image and it will allow you to update your name and image.

Answer (score -1):

Enter this is address bar:

```
chrome://flags/#enable-new-profile-management
```

Then select **Disabled** from drop down menu.

Comment: Google has disabled this control feature in Chrome 44.