# Hide Username Button in Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, browser

Latest version of Chrome now shows a button in the far-right on the tab-bar that denotes the user that's currently logged in to Chrome. I'm the only one using my computer and that button is kinda annoying, sitting there and staring at me all the time.

Is there a way to hide this button?

I'm using Mac OS X Yosemite and Google Chrome Version 39.0.2171.99 (64-bit).

[image]

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can disable this annoying button in `chrome://flags`. The option you are looking for is link to do so is *Enable new profile management system*, reachable using this direct link:

```
chrome://flags/#enable-new-profile-management
```

Disable it and restart chrome and the button will be gone.

Comment: Will I miss anything if I disable new profile management?

Comment: it doesn't seems you will. it goes back to the old behaviour of having only one user logged in the browser.

Comment: With Chrome version 44.0.2403.125, the button has re-appeared and this solution no longer works :(

Comment: @ehsanullahjan: as per [a comment in another question](http://superuser.com/questions/863990/how-do-i-remove-my-name-from-the-top-right-corner-of-chrome#comment1286153_864053), "For chrome 44, add --disable-new-avatar-menu when starting chrome. techdows.com/2015/06/chrome-44-disable-user-menu.html

Comment: This no longer works since Chrome 44. An alternative is install Slimjet from http://www.slimjet.com, a Chromium derivative, which offers a simple option "Show profile switching button on Window caption" to turn on/off this particular button.