# Removing the Chrome profile name button

Tags: google-chrome, user-profiles

I am unable to remove the Chrome profile name button.  I go to the Chrome flags and I disable
`Enable new profile management system Mac, Windows, Linux, Chrome OS, Android`

But when I restart my name is still next to the minimize button.  This would not normally be a huge deal, but the button interferes with another program I have that puts a useful icon there--it forces it to shift to the right and cover the minimize button.

Comment: In Chrome Version 48, it is removed. Instead, there is icon that you can click, which opens a drop down, and the name is in there.

Comment: Read this: http://superuser.com/a/1152506/6841