# How to hide Chrome user profile icon in toolbar

Tags: google-chrome

Well, my name no longer [shows in the upper-right](https://superuser.com/q/863990/57016), but now my user profile icon shows in the toolbar with Chrome 69. Is there a way to remove/hide the user profile icon from view?

[image: pizza icon]

Comment: The purpose of this button is to enforce you using the Google sync and to improve their cross device tracking for ads. The browser started to sniff around your logins to the google and is putting your profile photo there even if you didn't use the sync. There are no settings to edit avatar or hide this button intentionally.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

***Update: As of Google Chrome v71.x, this method no longer works.***

---

There is seemingly no official way to remove the People button.

However, as a workaround for Chrome 69.x, you can revert to the previous style that displays your name in the upper-right corner using a Chrome flag. *However, keep in mind that these flags are highly experimental; they may stop working or change at any time without notice.*

To revert to the previous UI style:

1. In a new tab, visit `chrome://flags/#top-chrome-md`
2. For the option **UI Layout for the browser's top chrome**, select **Normal** from the dropdown list
3. At the bottom of the page, click the **Relaunch Now.** button

Comment: No longer works, not even Normal is present in the list :/

Comment: @SpadarShut Sorry about that; I don't think there is anything we can do besides using a Chromium fork. As my answer above notes, "these flags are highly experimental; they may stop working or change at any time without notice"

I've updated my answer to reflect the change to Chrome. Thanks for the heads up!

Comment: no worries, I just added a note for others to save their time.

Answer (score 6):

You can't hide it, but you can prevent it from showing your profile picture. Click on your profile pic and hit "Open Guest Window". Helpful when you're shooting a video...

Comment: This is an actual solution to the question and as of now is the one that works best.

Comment: @Zombies how is it an actual solution, if an icon is still there, just with a different image.

Comment: Opening a guest window is not the same as opening a window under another profile. A guest window is similar to incognito mode, and cookies/history won't be preserved across sessions.

Answer (score -2):

If you just want to hide your portrait picture, you can change it with a built-in cartoon picture instead. Settings -> Chrome name and picture.