# Google account photo in chrome taskbar

Tags: google-chrome, taskbar, photos

How do I remove my Google account photo in chrome browser taskbar as of 9-20-18. It is taking of valuable space.  I do not want to log out of my google account just hide the photo from always being there.

If this is not a current option, please consider adding this to the next update. Allow user to move it into the settings bar like extensions you don't wish to see but are installed.  (I know what I look like,  I don't need a reminder)

Thanks 
Fran

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to remove just the new account photo, but there is a Chrome flag to revert to the previous UI, which will remove it.

Explained in this answer: https://superuser.com/a/1356519/917109